# Does java-me support threading?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me

does java-me support threading ? can you give me an example code that execute a function in another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using Threads in J2ME Applications](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading2/)

**Example:**

```
public class DoAnotherThing extends Thread {
    public void run(){
    // here is where you do something
    }
}
```

and Run it like this:

```
DoAnotherThing doIt = new DoAnotherThing();
doIt.start();
```

Comment: can i have another function named 'XYZ()' inside the 'DoAnotherThing' class. how to start the thread and call the function.

Comment: @vishnu: Look at these threads: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5440136 and http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Threads.shtml . May be these will help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Even the minimal Connected Limited Device Configuration [has it](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.0/jsr030/java/lang/Thread.html).  That page has an example, and some of the examples you find for the desktop will also apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to J2ME, then it does support threading. See an article [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading2/).